# BeforeDoubleClick and Intersect

Tags: vba, excel

I'm losing my mind:

I have this code in my Sheet 2, and its working great (see image for code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:D150")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A6:D150")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo ExitPoint
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not IsDate(Target(1)) Then
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox " You can't delete cell content :)" _
        , vbCritical, "Sara"
    End If
ExitPoint:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now I have an Excel sheet that is cells A:AC.

I want the formula applied to `A:D`, skip `E`, applied to `F:V`, skip `W:Z`, applied to `AA:AC`.

How can I implement these codes to multiple ranges?

I have tried many options and failed. I really appreciate any help and feedback.

Comment: What formula? Try `If Intersect(Target, Range("A:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`, then another similar line but with `Range("F:V")`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can either try to use `Union`. Something like:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Union(Range("A6:D150"),Range("F6:V150"),Range("AA6:AC150"))

If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then
'rest of your code
```

or you can directly use non-contiguous range notation:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("A6:D150,F6:V150,AA6:AC150")) Is Nothing Then
'rest of your code
```

Comment: OMG i cannot believe it was so easy. haha. thank you so much. you  are great